# Google Analytics referrals: What's the difference between t.co and twitter.com?

Tags: twitter, google-analytics

In Google Analytics' Pages report, I'm looking at a particular page on my site, then, under secondary dimensions, pulling up "Source/Medium." I'm seeing rows for both of these:

- t.co / referral
- twitter.com / social

What's the difference between these two? I understand that links shared on Twitter get wrapped in t.co URLs, but then what are the visits coming from twitter.com?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that @j-a-streich is right about that. From what I've seen, dealing with google analytics, you can't 100% predict why google ends up with the info they get - there are a lot of edge cases and gotchas. Here is what I have uncovered:

Twitter's official stance on how they handle referrer information: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-redirection-behavior

> t.co currently handles redirections by context and known user agents. We've taken care to preserve original referrers in all contexts where they are reliably provided.

But that doesn't actually help much, because they don't differentiate in that doc between t.co and twitter.com.

I did some testing, and it appears that whenever someone comes to your site direct from clicking a t.co wrapped link on twitter.com the referrer is the t.co link. That includes tweets and profile bios. That is also true for urls that were directly pasted into twitter and those that were pre-shortened by another shortener.

I also checked links from a client (old tweetdeck) and that showed up as t.co.

I wasn't actually able to find a valid source of twitter.com referrers.

My main problem with what @j-a-streich says is that he is appearing to say that the referrer will be maintained if someone goes from twitter to another site, then to you - and that won't happen. The referrer will be the other site.

Answer (score 0):

t.co is a link shortner similar to bitly, but with some assurance from twitter that the link isn't harmful (they say they scan the page before giving out the shortened URL).  People refered to your sites are getting there from a page that shared on twitter, and the people coming from twitter.com came from a twitter post.

So, basically:

```
t.co/referral  implies Twitter -> other page -> your site
twitter/social implies Twitter -> your site
```

Comment: that's what I was thinking originally, but the only location on a twitter profile page on Twitter.com where someone might click back to my site is in the specific spot where you can put in your site URL. And even _that_ link is wrapped in a t.co link

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this issue in my analytics as well, but I've just come to accept that referral data is not perfect and I treat it as so. I currently see direct, t.Co and twitter.Com referrals in GA and generally associate them all with Twitter. It's obviously hard to make a distinction with the direct visits, but there isn't much to do about that.

I think mobile device referrals play a part in it too because of the applications browser. I've noticed clicks in the android app show direct visits instead of t.co or twitter.